NI VISA in C#; problem reading replies from another PC over TCPIP
I have no problem opening a session ...... I manually punch in the IP address and socket, and the session opens successfully.  This program I am talking to is written to respond in a specific manner to certain strings sent through the TCPIP, e.g. "Do this thing" and "Do that thing".  In C#, I would make the call like so:
Session.RawIO.Write("Do this thing\r\n");

This works, because the program responds precisely as desired - it sets a mode, or turns off.  With each command I send to it, it places the string "OK" in the output buffer.  This is where the problem comes in - I can't read it.  RawIO.Read(), RawIO.ReadString(), etc all fail and time out.  I know from the programmer's perspective that the string "OK" is there because this is a well established program that I am talking to, and "OK" is only sent if the call is successful (which given that the response is as desired, I know for a fact it is).  In the VISA test panel, this fact is reinforced when I attempt a read.  The response "OK\r\n" appears, but the session still times out.  If I send the *IDN? query, the expected response appears, followed by a timeout.  The termination character is \n.  Every read function I have tried either through C# or the VISA test panel has failed.  Some colleagues in LabView are able to read this response with no problem......what am I doing wrong here?
Every Read() function available in NI VISA and Keysight VISA in C#.  NI VISA Test Panel for sanity.  (The program I am working on is in C#).  When the function call completes, I am supposed to be able to pull "OK" from the output buffer, but any and all VISA read calls time out (even if I see the OK in the test panel).
